# How can I change the logo in the Android search bar when I call onSearchRequested()

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

When I call onSearchRequested() a search bar appears on top of the screen with my app logo on the left. I want to change this icon for another icon that has something to do with the context of the search... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) there is no such method to do that. Apparently it picks up the logo of application.

However you can change the description.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/settings_description" 
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/settings_description"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    >
</searchable>
```

Comment: I can't believe it. I can't see a reason why I should not be able to change this. Thanks.